# Module (Album) could not be initial - ZendFramework3 - Tutorial

Tags: php, zend-framework, zf3

I tried to follow the [tutorial](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/overview/) of Zend Fremework 3, step by step, but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Album) could not be initialized.' in /var/www/html/skeleton-application/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php:203 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/skeleton-application/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php(175): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #1 /var/www/html/skeleton-application/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php(97): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('Album') #2 /var/www/html/skeleton-application/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(271): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #3 /var/www/html/skeleton-application/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(143): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #4 /var/www/html/skeleton-application/vendo in /var/www/html/skeleton-application/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php on line 203

This is my config/modules.config.php file:

```
return [
'Zend\Form',
'Zend\Db',
'Zend\Cache',
'ZendDeveloperTools',
'Zend\Router',
'Zend\Validator',
'Application',
'Album', ];
```

If I comment the 'Album' entry, the homepage is displayed properly.

Can someone give me some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show your composer.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error message I'm guessing you are at [setting up the Album module](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/modules/).

You need to check composer.json if the following is included:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
        "Album\\": "module/Album/src/"
    }
},
```

After that you need to run `composer dump-autoload` to update the autoloading rules.

If this doesn't help, please tell at what stage you are.

Comment: Thank you!
I solved just with the command 'composer dump-autoload'
I had missed this step, and I had not realized the importance of composer during the development phase.